# Generate dynamic QR codes in PHP

Tags: php, dynamic, qr-code

I am working on a project where we need to generate dynamic QR code. After the QR code is printed, we tend to make changes to the data so we need to generate dynamic QR code where there is no need to reprint the QR code.

I already used one of the [PHP library](http://phpqrcode.sourceforge.net/) to generate QR code but it is static which changes every time the data is altered.

This is an example of generating a QR code:

```
<?php 

    include('../lib/full/qrlib.php'); 

    // outputs image directly into browser, as PNG stream 
    QRcode::png('PHP QR Code :)');

?>
```

Is there anything that I can use to generate dynamic QR codes?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: add code to regenerate the qr code

Comment: `$id = "from Lord knows where..."; $dynamic = QRcode::png($id);`

Comment: @Ibu I added a sample code given in the documentation of PHP library. I am storing my QR codes in a database. So I would like to get that QR value from database and want to make some changes in it without effecting the QR code.

Comment: `$id = "from db..."; $dynamic = QRcode::png($id);`

Comment: @Fred-ii- I saw this code in the sample code that I posted in the question. So just by storing the generated QR code in $dynamic will make it dynamic? Can you please explain

Comment: yes it will. All you need is to query the db with a `WHERE` clause if you want, in the loop, use one of the variables you want from it and assign it to what I gave you as an example. I've done it before.

Comment: This question doesn't seem to be about generating the QRcode but instead how to "make them dynamic".

Answer (score 3):

Once printed/generated there is no way to change the content of a QRcode, it will always be the same.

But you can make it "dynamic" by storing in your QRcode a distinct URL* and on the server side pointed by the URL, you can change dynamically the content associated with this unique URL to whatever you want (with URL rewriting or the querying of a database), with the same QRcode.

*it can also be an id, depending on the usage, if you have an application reading the QRcode for example, the application could render the content associated with the id in question, and you could change which content is associated with each id in your application/backend without changing the QRcode.

On these both cases, you dynamically change on the application side the relation between the unique URL/id and the associated content, not on the representation side (the printed on screen/paper QRcode)

Comment: Thank you. Yes this is what we came up with. We will just store the URL in the QR code and URL will be pointed to the server side where we can change the data easily.

Comment: I store json in my qr codes so when my bulk scanner reads them the processing script finds the qr codes in the generated pdf and reads the json, the json contains the method and any variables I want to handle and then it processes it accordingly if I then want to alter the behaviour of the qr on scan I just alter the method (well little bit more complex but you get the idea)

Answer (score 0):

I just came up with a simple solution. Rather than just storing all the data on the QR code and trying to change it when altering the data, I would just store the URL in the QR code pointing to server side and the data can be stored there. It can easily be altered there and hence our QR code will remain same.

Comment: Like in my answer? ^^

Comment: Yes. The way you also described above.

Answer (score 0):

And yet there is another technically more practical way, which is the method where you can use an already ready-made API, like the one below, to create and manage your dynamic QR codes

```
<?php

$request = new HttpRequest();
$request->setUrl('https://qr-code-dynamic-and-static1.p.rapidapi.com/qrcode/dynamic');
$request->setMethod(HTTP_METH_POST);

$request->setHeaders([
'content-type' => 'application/json',
'api-key' => '<REQUIRED>',
'X-RapidAPI-Key' => '275379ed5emsh4b47685996c279ap1bcf73jsnc90319ab3f13',
'X-RapidAPI-Host' => 'qr-code-dynamic-and-static1.p.rapidapi.com'
]);

$request->setBody('{
"title": "This is a dynamic QR Code",
"description": "The link can be modified later",
"link": "https://rapidapi.com/updeploy-tools/api/qr-code-dynamic-and-static1"
}');

try {
$response = $request->send();

echo $response->getBody();
} catch (HttpException $ex) {
echo $ex;
}
```

See this link for more information: https://rapidapi.com/updeploy-tools/api/qr-code-dynamic-and-static1

Answer (score -1):

Try google API, I use for generating bitcoin QR code:

```
<?php
$btcadress = "BTCADRESS";
echo '<img src="https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=250x250&cht=qr&chl='.$btcadress.'">';
?>
```